# bash command truncating

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a bash file with the content

```
cd /var/www/path/to/folder
git pull
```

When I run it I get

```
: No such file or directorywww/path/to/folder
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        pull
```

Any idea why bash gets a truncated version of commands?

Comment: read the bash file with something like `hexdump -C` and check whether there is not a unexpected character such as `0d` in the file.

Comment: What happens when you run `sh -x script_name.sh`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have carriage returns (Windows text file line endings) in your bash script.  Remove them.

The bash file should look like this under `hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  63 64 20 2f 76 61 72 2f  77 77 77 2f 70 61 74 68  |cd /var/www/path|
00000010  2f 74 6f 2f 66 6f 6c 64  65 72 0a 67 69 74 20 70  |/to/folder.git p|
00000020  75 6c 6c 0a                                       |ull.|
00000024
```

But yours looks like this instead:

```
00000000  63 64 20 2f 76 61 72 2f  77 77 77 2f 70 61 74 68  |cd /var/www/path|
00000010  2f 74 6f 2f 66 6f 6c 64  65 72 0d 0a 67 69 74 20  |/to/folder..git |
00000020  70 75 6c 6c 0d 0a                                 |pull..|
```

Note the extra `0d`'s (hex 0D = decimal 13 = ASCII carriage return, ANSI `\r`) in front of the `0a`s (hex 0A = decimal 10 = ASCII linefeed, ANSI `\n`, which is what bash treats as the end of a line).

A carriage return is not whitespace in bash, so it is treated as part of the last argument on the command line. You're getting errors because the folder `/var/www/path/to/folder.git\r` doesn't exist and `pull\r` isn't a valid `git` subcommand.

When printed, a carriage return moves the cursor to the start of the line, which is why your error messages look wrong. Bash and git are printing something like `foo.bash: line 1: cd: /www/path/to/folder\r: No such file or directory` and `git: 'pull\r' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`, but after the `\r` moves the cursor to the start of the line, the tail end of each message overwrites its beginning.

There's a program called `dos2unix` that converts a text file from DOS to Unix:

```
dos2unix filename >newfilename
```

But that conversion really consists of nothing but deleting the carriage returns, which you could also do explicitly with `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' <filename >newfilename
```